# Stop submiting the form in Jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am trying to make some simple validation in bootstrap and jquery
Here is JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {

        if (($('input[name^=password]').val()) != password) {
            msg = 'Incorrect username or password';
            $(".modal-body").text(msg);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');

        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that form just continues?

Her is working bootply
http://www.bootply.com/7Tvg4nhuG4

**EDITED**

I have made something like this, but i am not sure is it ok to have two IF

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {

        if ((($('input[name^=password]').val()) != password) || (($('input[name^=username]').val()) != username)) {
            msg = 'Incorrect username or password';
            $(".modal-body").text(msg);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');

            return false;
        } 
            if ((($('input[name^=password]').val()) != "") || (($('input[name^=username]').val()) != "")) {
                return false;
        } 
        else {
            // do something
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your demo has errors and doesn't work for me in Chrome.

Comment: Don't do password validation on the client, also `var msg = "..."`

Answer (score 2):

You haven't told the form to not submit, so it doesn't not submit. :-)

```
if (($('input[name^=password]').val()) != password) {
    msg = 'Incorrect username or password';
    $(".modal-body").text(msg);
    $('#myModal').modal('show');

    return false; // this halts form submission
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways to do this.  Your submit method can return false, or you can pass in the event as a parameter and call *preventDefault* to stop the default action (submit).

**Return False**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {
        if (($('input[name^=password]').val()) != password) {
            msg = 'Incorrect username or password';
            $(".modal-body").text(msg);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');

            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

**PreventDefault**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(ev) {
        if (($('input[name^=password]').val()) != password) {
            msg = 'Incorrect username or password';
            $(".modal-body").text(msg);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');

            ev.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

With that said, I would strongly recommend using a framework for form validation as it makes your code a lot more modular and maintainable.  My personal preference is [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) which has been around for a long time and works very well, but there are many others are out there (eg. [Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/)).

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (($('input[name^=password]').val()) != "password") {
            msg = 'Incorrect username or password';
            $(".modal-body").text(msg);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');

        }
        else
        {
          $(this).submit();
        }
    });
});
```

PS: I also change `password` to `"password"` to avoid undefined var error.

#### Working bootply: http://www.bootply.com/YstRWS1HB3